# Facebook API : Empty Result for Ad Leads

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am building a PHP script based on Facebook Marketing API,

The API system works fine,

I can get the result for the campaigns, the ads, and full insights as well.

But, I want to get the result of the leads.

Note (1): I got admin access to the APP, the Ad account, and the page as well,

Note (2): App Status: In Development

Note (3) : I send the API request for "leads_retrieval" and "leads_retrieval",

```
$permissions = ['email','public_profile','leads_retrieval','ads_management', 'ads_read', 'business_management', 'read_audience_network_insights', 'read_insights', 'manage_pages', 'pages_show_list', 'pages_manage_cta','pages_manage_instant_articles', 'publish_pages', 'read_page_mailboxes'];
```

My Code to get the lead result :

```
$ad = new Ad('<AD_ID>');
$leads = $ad->getLeads();
$lead = $leads->getResponse()->getBody();

print_r($lead);
```

Result:

```
{"data":[]}
```

So for some reason, I still get the incorrect empty result for the leads!

Any idea about how to get the correct lead result for the Ad?

Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving/v2.9

Comment: You could try to inspect with the debug token utility if the token have the proper permision

Comment: @Matteo : could you please write a full reply with a code sample for the debug token in this case ?

Comment: hi! You can try to debug the Access Token using the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) Only for double check the token have the proper permission (This is not a real answer so I post as comment)

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem before but I found that I'm using incorrect ad_id.

double check you ad id, its possible that your not getting the full list of ad id inside adset.

use $ads->fetchAfter() to get the next page of ads

check complete code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500241/2588592