# Is it possible to retrieve Facebook Leads from ads that aren't active?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I've developed a C# Windows (desktop) app to retrieve ad leads details from Facebook, which works - but only active ads.

Is there a way to get the details for all adds even if they are not active, or is this a Facebook default setting.

The URL I'm using is...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[pageid]?access_token=[token]&fields=leadgen_forms{leads{form_id,ad_name,platform,created_time,field_data,custom_disclaimer_responses,retailer_item_id,is_organic}}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can get leads even if they are not active.

If you are using sdk you can use the following code

```
$ads = $adset->getAds(array(
AdFields::NAME,
AdFields::CONFIGURED_STATUS,
AdFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS,
AdFields::CREATIVE,
));
foreach ($ads as $ad) {

$ad_id = $ad->id;
$ad_name = $ad->name;

if($ad->configured_status=="ACTIVE"){}
}
```

check complete code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56500241/2588592

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't specially answer the question. The question mentions C# Desktop App while you have posted a PHP SDK solution. Is there are way to do this through the Graph API?